# How to make vertical svg rect height start from the bottom?

Tags: svg

**Desired behaviour**

Make a "bar chart" style icon with vertical bars.

**Actual Behaviour**

The following displays the desired result if I flip it with `scaleY()`.

```css
/* uncomment below for desired appearance */
/*
svg {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
*/
```

```html
<svg style="background: yellow" width="20" height="20" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
  <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="5" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="7" y="0" width="1" height="8" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="12" y="0" width="1" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="17" y="0" width="1" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to start the `height` from the bottom, rather than the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG's Y axis goes from the top down to the bottom (source)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions#The_grid].

In order to display the bars from the bottom of the icon, you need to calculate each bar's y coordinate accordingly: iconHeight - barHeight.

Adapted snippet:

```css
/* uncomment below for desired appearance */
/*
svg {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
*/
```

```html
<svg style="background: yellow" width="20" height="20" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
  <rect x="2" y="15" width="1" height="5" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="7" y="12" width="1" height="8" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="12" y="5" width="1" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <rect x="17" y="10" width="1" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```